# How to iteratively use a method of an iteratively created object in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to create object iteratively by using a class method inside the class that the objects belong to. So everytime I call that class method it creates an object, and ads it to a dictionary with its proper idex (both are class variables). My problem comes when I want to call the same method of every object, but iteratively and with a random attribute each time. My code is large so here I coded a another program with exactly what I'm looking for so it's easier to understand.

```
class new_class:
    objects = {} #this dictionary stores all objects of this class
    i = 0 #used to iterate the dictionary and define every object separately
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method(self, random): #<-- here goes the random elements that the method should be called with
        return random #sample usage of the random value
    @classmethod
    def object_creator(cls):
        cls.i += 1
        cls.objects[cls.i] = cls() <-- this creates a new object of its own class and adds it to the dictionary with the key of the also iterated "i" variable
            

while True:
    new_class.object_creator()
    #Here I want to call for the method of evey existing object with random attributes
```

Calling the object this way, with the dictionary and its index doesn't work because it just calls the last created object, since the current index belongs to him.

```
while True:
    new_class.object_creator()
    new_class.objects[new_class.i].method()
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible because I would have to essentialy "create new code" for each created object. The only pseudo-solution I've found is to make another loop and make iterate through the length of the dictionary, and call the method of the object whose index is the loop's one, but that calls each method at a time and not all of them at the same time.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking

Comment: First if all, what's the point of using a dict here? But leaving that aside, are you asking how to iterate over all the objects in your dict?

Comment: Of course it is going to call the method one at a time. Even computers have limitations. The fastest you call the methods on all objects would be using list comprehension or map.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using a dictionary so I can store each object of the class separately an access them. I'm not trying to iterate through the dict. For example if 3 object where created: dictionary = {object : 1, object : 2, object : 3}. I want to call for the method of each object separately and randomly in an iterative way. For example calling the method for the first object with the value 8, the one of the second one with 2, and the third one with 0. But I want to do it iterately so for each loop I get a new random value.

Comment: Ok, put your objects in a list, randomly shuffle the list, the iterate over the list and call the method... Or something equivalent to that

Comment: Again, your dictionary doesn't make any sense... You are just mapping increasing integers to each object(the reverse of what you posted in your comment), why a dict and not a list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Without a dictionary I wouldn't be able to identify each object and if I called it, it would just call the last created object.

Comment: *my question was why not a list instead of a dict* your dict serves *no purpose as a dict*

Answer (score 0):

By default, your code is executed sequentially by a single thread, so the calls to the method will be done one after another. But it may be very quick to call all your objects' method because computers are fast. And from the point of view of the programming language, calling `call_my_method_for_all_my_objects` is no different than calling `int("14")`.

If you really really (really) want to have code executed in parallel, you can have a look at **multi-threading** and **multi-processing**, but these are not easy topics. Don't bother with them if you don't actually want your program to execute faster or really need to have multiple code execution at the same time.

Using a `dict` instead of a `list` is not a *real* issue.

The problem with

```py
while True:
    new_class.object_creator()
    new_class.objects[new_class.i].method()
```

is that at each iteration of the loop, it will create a new object (which increments `i`), then call the `i`-th object (newly created) method. It means that each object will have its method called only once, and in the creation order which is also `i`-ascending.

As for a solution, I recommand you to create a function or a method that will call for each of your objects. I decided to implement it as a static method of the class :

```py
class new_class:
    objects = {}
    i = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self, random):
        return random

    @classmethod
    def object_creator(cls):
        cls.i += 1
        cls.objects[cls.i] = cls()

    @staticmethod  # static
    def call_each():
        for i, obj in new_class.objects.items():  # iterate over the objects
            print(obj.method(i))  # call each one's method, for example with its index
```

I used it like that :

```py
# let's create 3 items for demonstration purposes
new_class.object_creator(); new_class.object_creator(); new_class.object_creator()

print(new_class.objects)  # {1: <__main__.new_class object at 0x0000022B26285470>,
                          #  2: <__main__.new_class object at 0x0000022B262855C0>,
                          #  3: <__main__.new_class object at 0x0000022B262854A8>}

new_class.call_each()  # prints 1 2 3
```

If you want to provide a random value for each call, add `import random` to your script and change the `call_each` method to :

```py
    @staticmethod
    def call_each():
        for obj in new_class.objects.values():
            print(obj.method(random.random()))
```

so that

```py
new_class.call_each()  # prints 0.35280749626847374
                       #        0.22163283338299222
                       #        0.7368657784332368
```

If this does not answer your question, please please try to be extra clear in what you ask.